# Getting an undefined reference error

Tags: c++

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to figure out why I am getting the following error:

```
$~/display/triangleDisplayable.cc:4: undefined reference to `Displayable::Displayable()'
```

I am trying to abstract a class `Displayable` and have a class `triangleDisplayable` that implements its methods. The two header files I have are "Displayable.h":

```
    class Displayable {

    public:
        Displayable();

        virtual int getSizeOfArrays() = 0;
        void display(int size);

    private:
        virtual void init() = 0;
        virtual int getSizeOfPointsArray() = 0;
        virtual int getSizeOfNormalsArray() = 0;

    };
```

and "triangleDisplayable.h"

```
    #include "Displayable.h"

    class triangleDisplayable : public Displayable 
    {

    public:
        triangleDisplayable();
        int getSizeOfArrays();

    private:
        void init();
        int getSizeOfPointsArray();
        int getSizeOfNormalsArray();

    };
```

And then I have "Displayable.cc"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Displayable.h"

    Displayable::Displayable() {
        std::cout << "testing Displayable constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void Displayable:display(int size) {
    }

    int main () {
        return 0;
    }
```

and "triangleDisplayable.cc"

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "triangleDisplayable.h"

    triangleDisplayable::triangleDisplayable() : Displayable() {
    }

    int triangleDisplayable::getSizeOfArrays() {
        return 0;
    }

    void triangleDisplayable::init() {
    }

    int triangleDisplayable::getSizeOfPointsArray() {
        return 0;
    }

    int triangleDisplayable::getSizeOfNormalsArray() {
        return 0;
    }

    int main () {
        return 0;
    }
```

I have been trying to follow along with various tutorials to learn how to do abstraction in C++, but I have not really been able to find any helpful solutions to this. I believe that all of my `#include`s are correct, which I read is a common problem. The error message seems to indicate that the problem is the line

```
    triangleDisplayable::triangleDisplayable() : Displayable() {
    }
```

I have tried to compile without the `: Displayable()` but I get the same error. Is there perhaps a problem with my syntax in my header files?

Comment: Did you compile Displayable.cc and linked to the object file?

Comment: Try defining the constructor.. i.e. instead of Displayable(); try Displayable() {}; in the Displayable.h file. This will be called in all your subclass constructors

Comment: I was not linking the two source files together. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the error is in tool invocation. You need to link the two source files together (e.g. `g++ -o foo a.cc b.cc`). And remove one of the `main` functions, as you can't have two different ones.

Comment: thank you, that worked great! I can't believe I didn't catch the two main functions.